# WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration returns "Retrieving the COM class factory ... failed"

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am trying to run .NET tool that uses [WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151456%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to mess with remote IIS site config. Although it works well from other computers, my machine refuses to connect with following exception raised by the method call:

`Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID {9FDB6D2C-90EA-4E42-99E6-38B96E28698E} from machine [name] failed due to the following error: 80070005.`

I tried to run the app in x86 build configuration, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

*This looks like permissions issues. Try this.*

1. Administrative Tools > Component Services > Computer > My Computer.
2. Right Click on My computer > properties - Default Properties Tab
3. Check the "Default Impersonation Level" if its "Anonymous" set it to "Identity"

*If above doesn't help. Try this as well.*

1. Go to the Start-Run menu item or search  "DCOMCNFG" and hit enter. 
   This should load the "Component Services" MMC (you can also load from Administrative Tools - Component Services"
2. Expand "Component Services"
3. Expand "Computers"
4. Expand "My Computer"
5. Select the "DCOM Config" item
6. Select the "{9FDB6D2C-90EA-4E42-99E6-38B96E28698E}" item. 
   Right click and select Properties
7. Under "Launch and Activation Permissions" select the "Customize" option. Click the "Edit" button Click the "Add" button to add your account.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply! Unfortunately, it is already set to "Identify".

Comment: 80070005 is Access Denied on COM component. If its not at server level, you may like to check it at registry or file level (I would try ProcMon in this case). If you have UAC enabled, make sure you run your .net tool using "Run As Admin.." mode.

Comment: Added another option to try in my answer above. Try if that helps.

Comment: Curiously, the CLSID is missing from that list, both on my computer and the target machine. I tried to find the name of this... service in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/CLSID, but it's not there, also.